# A question about the proof of Theorem 5.21 in Van der Vaar(1998)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

If we know that $\hat\theta_n\overset{p}\to\theta_0$, how does the following equation
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n}V_{\theta_0}\cdot(\theta_0-\hat\theta_n)+\sqrt{n}o_p(|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|)=G_n\psi_{\theta_0}+o_p(1)\qquad\qquad(1)
\end{equation}
become
$$\sqrt{n}V_{\theta_0}\cdot(\hat\theta_n-\theta_0)=-G_n\psi_{\theta_0}+o_p(1)?\qquad\qquad(2)$$

---

This is part of proof for Theorem 5.21 on page 52-53 in Van der Vaar(1998).  I wonder how can the term $\sqrt{n}o_p(|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|)$ in equation (1) be omitted. The author also provide an inequality between these two equations. That is,
$$\sqrt{n}|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|\le|V_{\theta_0}^{-1}|\sqrt{n}|V_{\theta_0}(\hat\theta_n-\theta_0)|=O_p(1)+o_p(\sqrt{n}|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|)\qquad\quad (3)$$

He also writes, "This implies that $\hat\theta_n$ is $\sqrt{n}$-consistent: The left side is bounded in probability. Inserting this
in equation (1), we obtain equation (2)."

Comment: The author argues two things. First, since $\sqrt{n}|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|-o_p(\sqrt{n}|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|)\leq O_p(1)$ he infers that $\sqrt{n}|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|=O_P(1)$ (which I can't manage to prove). Second, that $o_p(O_P(1))=o_P(1)$ (which is easy to prove).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. By your first observation, we have $\sqrt{n}|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|-\sqrt{n}|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|\cdot o_p(1)\le O_p(1)$. Thus  $\sqrt{n}|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|\le O_p(1)/(1- o_p(1))$, which implies $\sqrt{n}|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|=O_p(1)$. By your second observation, the term $\sqrt{n}o_p(|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0|)=o_p(1)$. Therefore it is omitted in equation (1).

Comment: So your question is answered, isn't it ?

Comment: I think so. Thanks for your useful comment.